# Base64 Audio Issue in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, base64

I am creating windows phone 8 application, and getting Base64String Audio from Web Service response, How do I convert it and play it using MediaElement or? I tried but not getting the result. See my code.

```
String file = "askjakfgksdguuqeiqheiqe/34q/asas2j/asasaadadada";
byte[] playbyte = Convert.FromBase64String(file);
MemoryStrem stream = new MemoryStream(playbyte,0,playbyte.Length);
MediaElement.SetSource(stream);
MediaElement.Play();
```

I also tried using IsolatedStorage but didn't succeed.

How to do it?

Comment: what is the format of the resulting audio?

Comment: @esskar it is AIFF, thanks for ur quick response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AIFF is not supported on WP8, see also [Supported media codecs for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff462087(v=vs.105).aspx) as a reference.

Comment: ok, can I able to play it using SoundEffect? Please reply.Thanks1!!

Comment: i changed my answer: AIFF is not supported by WP8 at all